# mysqld space header page error (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql

After formatting C and not having my original ini file I copied my templated mysql file which tells mysql to use a file per table and other things. I set the path and port appropriately and I get this error when I run it. How do I fixed this? AFAIK I haven't done anything to the files since it was working

```
>"D:\ProgramData\mysql-5.5.32-win32\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="D:/ProgramData/my.ini" --console
130725 18:51:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 96.0M
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\ibdata1
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
130725 18:51:01 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
130725 18:51:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130725 18:51:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130725 18:51:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
130725 18:51:01 [ERROR] Aborting
130725 18:51:01 [Note] D:\ProgramData\mysql-5.5.32-win32\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```